# Dynamic linking

Tags: c++, dynamic, linker

How can I check how dynamic linking is acheved on my system? And what restrictions are placed on dynamically linked code. What requirements are placed on code for it to be dynamically linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It almost looks like you are asking if there is any *portable* way to check on your OS capabilities, regardless of what the OS is.

The only thing like that which can be said is, "Read the documentation".

For the OS'es I know about, Windows uses DLLs for dynamic linking, and Unixes use `.so` files. Both provide the capability to either manually or automaticly load the library's entry points.

Comment: or even more comprehensive would be to `<sadism>` *read the `libtool` sources* `</sadism>`.

Comment: Remember that DLLs are not portable across OS's.  A Windows DLL will not work on a Unix or Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic linking is performed at run time by the Operating system,

- hence it has following restrictions:

  1. OS specific.

     eg.  A Windows .dll can not be directly linked to linux,
     you need to build it there and generate .so and vice versa.
  2. Dlls are platform specific:

     eg. An X64 dll can not be linked to Win32 project.
  3. They are also Configuration specific:

     eg. If u have a release dll, you can not linked it to another project 
     which configuration is set to  Debug.
  4. It also depends on calling convention:

     for eg. if your .dll project has calling convention set to __cdecl and
     and the callee sets its calling convention to __stdcall, it may lead to      problems like run  time exceptions.

Comment: Actually, there's very little to stop you from using a release DLL in a Debug project, and this is in fact very common. For instance, the Windows API is made available by loading Kernel32.DLL, User32.DLL, GDI.DLL etc into your process. And you almost always load the Windows release DLLs, even while debugging. (Most developers don't even know what the debug version of Windows is called - it's the _checked_ build)